# Recorrer un dataframe y seleccionar solo ciertos valores de las filas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de recorrer toda una tabla de un *dataframe*, en principio que me distinga de la columna `depth` los valores desde 8351 a 8471 y luego que dentro de ese rango tome los valores que no tengan la palabra **NOHAY** en la columna `sw`.

Adjunto el código que tengo hasta ahora pero me da este error:

> tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row['depth']>= 8351 and row['depth']<=8471:
        if row['sw'] != 'NOHAY':
            lista_sw = []
            lista_sw.append(df['sw'][i])
print(lista_sw)
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea te arroja el error? ¿En `lista_sw.append(df['sw'][i])`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un trozo de tus datos, para que pueda hacer pruebas con él? Preferiblemente en formato csv (o sea, delimitado por comas) o si no en forma de tabla de texto. Creo que hay una forma mucho más eficiente de lograr lo que buscas, sin necesidad de usar `iterrows()` que siempre es la forma más lenta. Pero sin datos de prueba no me atrevo a responder.

Answer (score 1):

El error es bastante claro, estás usando una string como índice de una tupla.

Si quieres acceder al índice de una tupla o lista necesitas usar un número entero. Ej:

```
mi_tupla=('a','b')
mi_tupla[1]
```

Pero al parecer estás haciendo:

```
mi_tupla["1"]
```

Puedes solucionarlo con un `int("1")` o en tu caso `int(i)`. Aunque, como no veo el resto de tu código, no sé porque el valor de `i` es de tipo string. Probablemente esto también sea un error, porque normalmente los índices se suelen incrementar o reducir para alcanzar otros valores adyacentes y no puedes hacerlo si son de tipo string.

En resumen, verifica el valor de `i` con `print(type(i))` y de ser de tipo string puedes solucionarlo con:

```
lista_sw.append(df['sw'][int(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he probado y la forma más eficiente para resolver esa tarea y sin que de error, sería cambiando el bucle por operadores lógicos, así:

```
cond1 = df["depth"] >= 8351 
cond2 = df["depth"] <= 8471
cond3 = df["sw"] != "NOHAY"
Tabla_condic = cond1 & cond2 & cond3
print(df[Tabla_condic])
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de un dataframe de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'depth':[8250,8351,8450,8150,8580,8420,8390,8370,8150,8440],
              'sw':['SIHAY','NOHAY','SIHAY','SIHAY','SIHAY','NOHAY','SIHAY','NOHAY','SIHAY','SIHAY']})

print(df)
```

Que nos daría una salida así:

```
  depth     sw
0   8250  SIHAY
1   8351  NOHAY
2   8450  SIHAY
3   8150  SIHAY
4   8580  SIHAY
5   8420  NOHAY
6   8390  SIHAY
7   8370  NOHAY
8   8150  SIHAY
9   8440  SIHAY
```

Puedes crear uno nuevo filtrado, sobreescribir `df`, imprimirlo, etc. En este caso creo uno nuevo:

```
df2 = df[(df['depth'].between(8351, 8471)) & (df['sw'] != 'NOHAY')]
```

que sería:

```
print(df2)

   depth     sw
2   8450  SIHAY
6   8390  SIHAY
9   8440  SIHAY
```